# Swift UI Navigation Views

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I am writing an app that logs in users and allows them to make a new account if the email is not associated with an active account.Once they press sign up, the view should transition to a new view that prompts them to give information about them, name, age, etc. I have a bug where it does not transition, or does and then goes right back to sing up view.

Here is the code for the login view

```
@State var email: String = ""
@State var password: String = ""
@State var UserProfileActive = false
 NavigationView{
 Button(action:
            { if email != "" && password != ""{
                    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password){authResult, error in
                            if let e = error{
                                 print(e)
                            }
                          //successfully regiester.     
                          else{
                           //Here I should transition to UserProfile() View
                                 UserProfileActive = true
                                        NavigationLink(destination: UserProfile(), isActive: $UserProfileActive) {
                                             EmptyView()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }}
                    ) {
                        SIGNUP()
                    }
}
```

Within the navigation view, I get sent here. I have no idea what this is

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have `View` hierarchy *inside* your `Button` action. Move the view code *outside* of the action and change your `@State` variables that affect the hierarchy from the `action`

Comment: @jnpdx when you say view code, what part are you referring to specifically? And where specifically do I move it to? At the end of the navigation view?

Comment: `NavigationLink`, `EmptyView` and likely `SIGNUP` are all view code. You need to move it *outside* your `Button`'s action. It should probably be inside your `NavigationView` but that's up to you.

Comment: I moved the NavigationLink code as well as the EmptyView to the bottom of the navigation view, but I still get sent to that code in the screen shot I have posted, and nothing happens after that

Comment: Does this actually crash? Or is it stopping on a debugger breakpoint somewhere?

Comment: The program does not crash, just seems to finish all the code associated with hitting the button, it never hits the sign up view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246519/discussion-between-kyle-zeller-and-jnpdx).

Comment: You need to have something like `if userProfileActive { LoggedInView() } else { LoggedOutView() }` and set `userProfileActive` in your `Button`'s `action`